# What would a 5 point 2nd order central finite difference formula look like?

Tags: calculus

I am aware of the usual 2nd order central difference formula that uses 3 points with error $O(h^2)$
$$ \frac{u_{j-1}-2u_j + u_{j+1}}{h^2}$$
But what would a 5 point central difference formula look like and what would its error term be?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064829/331661
They use (up to second order)$$\begin{align}u_{j-1}&=u_j-u'_j h+\frac 12 u''_j h^2\\u_{j+1}&=u_j+u'_j h+\frac 12 u''_j h^2\end{align}$$
We can write the next positions, $j-2$ and $j+2$ as $$\begin{align}u_{j-2}&=u_j-u'_j (2h)+\frac 12 u''_j (2h)^2\\u_{j+2}&=u_j+u'_j (2h)+\frac 12 u''_j (2h)^2\end{align}$$
If you add all these equations together you get $$u_{j-2}+u_{j-1}+u_{j+1}+u_{j+2}=4u_j+\frac 12 u''_jh^2(2^2+1^2+1^2+2^2)=4u_j+5u''_jh^2$$
I can then get $$u''_j=\frac{u_{j-2}+u_{j-1}-4u_j+u_{j+1}+u_{j+2}}{5h^2}$$